# What to count when counting all rows MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, count

Is there any difference in the performance, or the background execution behavior when counting `*` , any custom field ( `n` ), or the `primary id` in MySQL?

What exactly does `*` refer to in the query, and how does it differ from those two other ways?

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM t;
SELECT COUNT( id ) FROM t;
SELECT COUNT( n ) FROM t;
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Assume, that neither `id` nor `n` is null at any record.

Comment: Count(*) counts all, count(id) will only count non nulls

Comment: You can't really compare performance of queries that return different results :-?

Comment: Let's assume, that the primary id is not null at any record. I guess, that's rather usual.

Comment: Correct.  The question is not actually about performance because the options provided are asking two different questions.  If a table has a PK then it's almost certain that count(*) would be implemented by counting the rows in the index.

Comment: For counting all rows, you can also use `count(1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
COUNT(*) will include NULLS
COUNT(column_or_expression) won't.
```

This means `COUNT(any_non_null_column)` will give the same as `COUNT(*)` of course because there are no NULL values to cause differences.

Generally, `COUNT(*)` should be better because any index can be used because `COUNT(column_or_expression)` may not be indexed or SARGable

From [ANSI-92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) (look for "Scalar expressions   125")

Case:

> a) If `COUNT(*)` is specified, then the result is the cardinality of **T**.
>
> b) Otherwise, let **TX** be the single-column table that is the result of applying the 
>           to each row of **T** and eliminating null values. 
>          If one or more null values are eliminated, then a completion condition is 
>          raised: warning- null value eliminated in set function.

The same rules apply to SQL Server and Sybase too at least

*Note: `COUNT(1)` is the same as `COUNT(*)` because 1 is a non-nullable expression.*

Answer (score 1):

[`count(*)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) has some optimizations in certain cases (querying a single MyISAM table with no `where` clause), which could to be the case in the OP, depending on the storage engine. If your query doesn't hit this special case, MySQL will have to construct an execution plan and run the query normally, which would be just as good (or bad) as `count(my_primary_key)` if you have a primary key.

Long story short - don't over think it. Just use `count(*)` and let the database worry about optimizing your query. After all, that's what it's build for.

Comment: count(*) and count(primary key) are not the same

Comment: @Mihai - Why are they different?

Comment: @RickJames One counts null the other doesn`t.

Comment: @Mihai primary keys don't have mulls - neither count nulls.

Answer (score 1):

For InnoDB tables, you will probably find that the "smallest" index is used for `COUNT(*)`, `COUNT(1)`, or `COUNT(id)`.  To see this, do `EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(...) FROM tbl;`.

If you have no secondary indexes, then the 'table' must be scanned.

Note that each secondary key includes the column(s) of the `PRIMARY KEY`.  So, for

```
PRIMARY KEY(a, b)
INDEX c_d (c, d)
```

probably any count on any of those 4 columns, or `(1)` or `(*)` will use the `c_d` index.

`COUNT(e)` will need to scan the table.